# Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, arguments

My goal is to have a user type in coordinates (longitude and latitude) into a form. The form takes response in params hash and uses google geocoder API to specify a location. I then want this location to be compared with another users location with a distance matrix API which would find distance between the users.

Here are my routes:

```
get "/users/:id/runwith" => 'application#runwith'
get "/reversegeocode" => 'application#reversegeocode'
```

Here is controller:

```
def runwith 
end
def reversegeocode
@users = User.all
lat = params['longitude']
long = params['latitude']
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=#{lat},#{long}"
result = open(url).read
parsed_result = JSON.parse(result)
@location = parsed_result['results'][0]['formatted_address'].gsub(" ", "%20")
end
```

My custom method:

```
private
def location some_runner
@users = User.all
distance_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=#{@location}&destinations=#{some_runner.location}"
distance_parsed_result = JSON.parse(open(distance_url).read)
{distance: distance_parsed_result['rows'][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["text"], duration: distance_parsed_result['rows'][0]["elements"][0]["duration"]["text"]}
end
helper_method :location
end
```

My form html:

```
<% if session[:user_id] %>
<h1> You are already logged in there is no need to specify your location </h1>
<%else%>

<h1> Since you aren't logged in, where are you currently? </h1> 
<form action ="/reversegeocode">

  Longitude:<input name ="longitude" type ="text" placeholder="coordinates">

  Latitude:<input name ="latitude" type ="text" placeholder="coordinates">

  <input type="submit">

</form>


<%end%>
```

My end result reversegeocode.html.erb:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<h1> <%=@location.gsub("%20"," ")%> </h1>

<% data = location.location(user) %>

<!-- <h1>You are <%#=data[:distance]%> far from <%#=data[:duration]%> </h1> -->
<%end%>
```

However I keep getting the error wrong number of arguments (0 for 1), def location some_runner. Why??

Comment: Should `location.location(user)` be `@location.location(user)`?

Comment: When I do that I get an error saying this: undefined method `location' for "2603-2633%20Ewing%20Avenue,%20Evanston,%20IL%2060201,%20USA":String   The string above would be the coordinates I gave it.

Comment: I was not suggesting, but wondering whether you even had a variable `location`. I now see it's a helper method. In that case, that is definitely the source of the problem. `location` calls the helper with 0 arguments; then `.location(user)` calls a method on whatever `location` would return. If you just want to call the helper, `location(user)` should suffice.

Comment: I just specified data variable so that their is only one API request and so that code is dry when I call:
<!-- <h1>You are <%#=data[:distance]%> far from <%#=data[:duration]%> </h1> -->

Comment: Sorry, I just realised something and rewrote my comment.

Comment: So i would say helper_method :location(user)? Because that gives me error. Again srry i am very new to rails

Comment: No, just `location(user)`, if it is correctly registered as a helper method; that is the whole point of them, that you can just call them from views.

Comment: Dude it works! But I cant quite wrap my head around it. What is the helper method doing in this case?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It's doing what you said it should do in `def location ... end`. What else? Or, do you mean what [`helper_method`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method) is doing? (Which would be, declaring `location` to be a helper, thus available as a function in views.)

Comment: Ok I get it. So just to clarify please help me understand how: data = location(user) works while date = @location.location(user) didn't. Srry again for being so dumb.

Comment: `@location.location(user)` calls a `location` method on the `@location` object (which is presumably a model, and it obviously doesn't define such a method, given your error message above). `location(user)` calls the `location` helper. `location.location(user)` is equivalent to `location().location(user)` - calls `location` helper with no arguments, then calls `location` method on the result (or would have, if there was no error).

Comment: Thanks @Amadan that was very helpful! It works!